# Haskell: Non-exhaustive patterns with Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: haskell, recursion, pattern-matching, primes, non-exhaustive-patterns

I wanted to use this code of Sieve of Eratosthenes from this page: http://en.literateprograms.org/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes_(Haskell)#chunk def:primes_naive

Only a bit modified, so it only shows the primes up to a number:

```
primes :: Integral a => a -> [a]
primes m  = sieve [2..m]
  where
    sieve (p:xs) = p : sieve [x|x <- xs, x `mod` p > 0]
```

But in WinGHCi always the error comes (example 10):

```
primes 10
[2,3,5,7*Main> *** Exception: eratosthenes.hs:4:5-55: Non-exhaustive patterns in function sieve
```

I know this error from recursive functions, where for example cases are missing, but what is missing here?

Comment: Although the formulation looks like the sieve of Eratosthenes, the evaluation is actually different and very slow. You might be interested in [this article](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf).

Comment: change it to ``sieve (p:xs) | p*p<=m = p : sieve [x|x <- xs, x `mod` p > 0] | otherwise = (p:xs)`` for a fix and a tremendous speedup.

Answer (score 5):

Unlike the version on the website,  your function will eventually consume the whole list,  so you need a pattern matching for `[]`

```
sieve [] = []
```

Answer (score 2):

As zakyggaps said, your version evaluates the function `sieve` with a finite list `[2..m]` which eventually will evaluate the empty list case.

Another way to solve this problem is to use the function `takeWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]` to evaluate `sieve [2..]` until you reach your limit m.

```
primes :: Integral a => a -> [a]
primes m  = takeWhile (\p -> p <= m) $ sieve [2..]
  where
    sieve (p:xs) = p : sieve [x|x <- xs, x `mod` p > 0]
```